# Hadoop Map Reduce program for hashing

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have written a Map Reduce Program in Hadoop for hashing all the records of the file, and appending the hased value as an additional attribute to each record and then output to Hadoop file system
This is the code i have written

```
public class HashByMapReduce
{
public static class LineMapper extends Mapper<Text, Text, Text, Text>
{
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(Text key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException,    InterruptedException
      {
        key.set("single")
        String line = value.toString();
            word.set(line);
            context.write(key, line);

    }
}
public static class LineReducer
extends Reducer<Text,Text,Text,Text>
{
    private Text result = new Text();
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values,
    Context context
    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        String translations = "";
        for (Text val : values)
        {
            translations = val.toString()+","+String.valueOf(hash64(val.toString())); //Point of Error 

        result.set(translations);
        context.write(key, result);
        }
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = new Job(conf, "Hashing");
    job.setJarByClass(HashByMapReduce.class);
    job.setMapperClass(LineMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(LineReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    job.setInputFormatClass(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
}
```

I have written this code with the logic that Each line is read by the Map method which assigns all value to a single key which then passes to same Reducer method. which the passes each values to hash64() function.

But i see its passing a null value(empty value) to hash function. I am not unable to figure it out why? Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you use `org.w3c.dom.Text`?

Comment: Sorry .. dont know how it got inserted there @ThomasJungblut

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of the problem is most probably due to the use of `KeyValueTextInputFormat`. From [Yahoo tutorial](https://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module4.html) :

```
  InputFormat:          Description:       Key:                     Value:

  TextInputFormat       Default format;    The byte offset          The line contents 
                        reads lines of     of the line                            
                        text files

  KeyValueInputFormat   Parses lines       Everything up to the     The remainder of                      
                        into key,          first tab character      the line
                        val pairs
```

It's breaking your input lines wrt `tab` character. I suppose there is no `tab` in your lines. As a result the `key` in the `LineMapper` is a whole line while nothing is being passed as `value` ( not sure `null` or empty ).

From your code I think you should better use `TextInputFormat` class as your inputformat which produces line offset as `key` and the complete line as `value`. This should solve your problem.

**EDIT :** I run your code with following changes, and it seems to work fine:

1. Changed inputformat to `TextInputFormat` and accordingly change declaration of the Mapper
2. Added proper `setMapOutputKeyClass` & `setMapOutputValueClass` to the `job`. These are not mandatory but often creates problem on running.
3. Removed your `ket.set("single")` and added a private outkey to the Mapper.
4. Since you provided no details of `hash64` method, I used `String.toUpperCase` for testing.

If the issue persists, then I'm sure that your hash method hasn't handle `null` well.

Full code :

```
 import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
 import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
 import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
 import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
 import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
 import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
 import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
 import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
 import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
 import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

 public class HashByMapReduce {
 public static class LineMapper extends
        Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {
    private Text word = new Text();
    private Text outKey = new Text("single");

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String line = value.toString();
        word.set(line);
        context.write(outKey, word);
    }
}

public static class LineReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {
    private Text result = new Text();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String translations = "";
        for (Text val : values) {
            translations = val.toString() + ","
                    + val.toString().toUpperCase(); // Point of Error

            result.set(translations);
            context.write(key, result);
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = new Job(conf, "Hashing");
    job.setJarByClass(HashByMapReduce.class);
    job.setMapperClass(LineMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(LineReducer.class);
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
}
```

}

Comment: Then I hafta check your code once again, but remember `KeyValueInputFormat` will always produce erroneous result unless intentional.

Comment: which version of Hadoop you are using ?

Comment: You are a goldsmith!!. it worked.. I missed these job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);